# Set up nginx as transparent caching server

Tags: nginx

I'll try to define my problem more clearly. I have a server block in my nginx.conf that defines a transparent caching server, it works fine, I can browse internet by setting the proxy in my browser, and the proxy_access.log does show my access.

```
server
{
    listen 8008;
    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy_access.log;
}
```

Now in my virtual domain, I have this block:

```
location ~* \.(|png|jpg|jpeg|mp3|ico)$ {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8008;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header        Referer    '';
    proxy_set_header        Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

My intention was to send all requests to those files to my transparent caching server, and experimenting possibly to modify the request header. I then have some pages embedded with some `.jpeg, .png, .ico` files, some external, and some internal (residing on my server), when the page is loaded, I expect to see access to those file logged in `/var/log/nginx/proxy_access.log`, but nothing shows in there.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks,

Comment: is the second location block inside or outside the server block? Should be inside it.

Comment: @shonkylinuxuser really? the second block belongs to a different virtual server, in which the `location /` has already defined.